# AWS CloudFormation resource limit of 200

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, serverless-framework

I have an app with a lot of resources (a bunch of DynamoDB tables, lambda functions, etc) and apparently I've run into the hard limit of 200 resources. The specific error is:

```
Template format error: Number of resources, 204, is greater than the maximum allowed, 200
```

The error message is pretty clear, but I'd like to know what my options are. Worst case, I can split the app into several pieces. Are there any alternative strategies?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create **nested stacks** that would also have the advantage of simpler testing, improving re-use and using different roles.

Common practice is to separate out different layers into different stacks. For example, build the VPC in one stack, deploy back-end in another stack and the front-end in another stack.

See: [Use Nested Stacks to Create Reusable Templates and Support Role Specialization](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/devops/use-nested-stacks-to-create-reusable-templates-and-support-role-specialization/)

Comment: Thanks. it looks like cross stack referencing is also an option. Do you have any experience with that?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have any knowledge about that.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein can you provide more code/documentation for it.

Comment: @AshishKadam Please create a new Question rather than asking a question as a comment on old old question.

Comment: Hi John, I am running into the same error. Can you please help me with this - https://stackoverflow.com/q/68939710/1379286

Answer (score 3):

The resource limit is now 500 if that helps!

[AWS CloudFormation now supports increased limits on five service quotas](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2020/10/aws-cloudformation-now-supports-increased-limits-on-five-service-quotas/)

Answer (score 1):

I have to face the same problem in the serverless framework. What I do!

Create microservices for each module like Authentication, User-management, SMS Gateway, Notification etc. that helps to manage code and AWS resources.

At the end expose API to create AWS custom domain and assign cloud formation to it.

I follow this [blog](https://medium.com/type-faster/how-to-call-multiple-serverless-micro-services-under-the-same-domain-972b5b9e49dd), it's help and Serverless also suggest flow [link.](https://serverless.com/blog/serverless-workaround-cloudformation-200-resource-limit/#break-your-web-api-into-microservices)

Comment: how did you run locally? I use sls offline start but having multiple services makes is hard to start one by one right?