# How to keep the same API Gateway URL for all CloudFormation nested stacks?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, aws-api-gateway, aws-sam

I am developing a REST API using AWS Lambda, API Gateway and CloudFormation. I hit the Cloudformation 500 resources limit, so I had to go for `nested stacks`. Below is what I tried.

**template.yaml**

```
    AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
    Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
    Description: >
      aws-restapi
    
      Sample SAM Template for aws-restapi
      
    # More info about Globals: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/docs/globals.rst
    Globals:
      Function:
        Timeout: 5
        VpcConfig:
            SecurityGroupIds:
              - sg-041f2459dcd921e8e
            SubnetIds:
              - subnet-0381db2d
              - subnet-c4d5c4cb
              - subnet-af5c03c8
              - subnet-7487df28
              - subnet-d139d69c
              - subnet-e9e88bd7
    
    Resources:
      GetAllAccountingTypesFunction:
        Type: AWS::Serverless::Function # More info about Function Resource: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#awsserverlessfunction
        Properties:
          CodeUri: aws-restapi/
          Handler: source/accounting-types/accountingtypes-getall.getallaccountingtypes
          Runtime: nodejs14.x
          Events:
            GetAllAccountingTypesAPIEvent:
              Type: Api # More info about API Event Source: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#api
              Properties:
                Path: /accountingtypes/getall
                Method: get
      GetAccountingTypeByIDFunction:
        Type: AWS::Serverless::Function # More info about Function Resource: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#awsserverlessfunction
        Properties:
          CodeUri: aws-restapi/
          Handler: source/accounting-types/accountingtypes-byid.getbyid
          Runtime: nodejs14.x
          Events:
            GetAllAccountingTypesAPIEvent:
              Type: Api # More info about API Event Source: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#api
              Properties:
                Path: /accountingtypes/getbyid
                Method: get
       # DependsOn: GetAllAccountingTypesFunction
    
      NestedStack:
        Type: AWS::CloudFormation::Stack
        Properties:
          TemplateURL: template_user.yaml

NestedStackTwo:
    Type: AWS::CloudFormation::Stack
    Properties:
      TemplateURL: template_two.yaml
      
    
      LambdaRole:
        Type: 'AWS::IAM::Role'
        Properties:
          AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
            Version: "2012-10-17"
            Statement:
              - Effect: Allow
                Principal:
                  Service:
                    - lambda.amazonaws.com
                Action:
                  - 'sts:AssumeRole'
          Path: /
          ManagedPolicyArns:
            - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole
          Policies:
            - PolicyName: root
              PolicyDocument:
                Version: "2012-10-17"
                Statement:
                  - Effect: Allow
                    Action:
                      - ec2:DescribeNetworkInterfaces
                      - ec2:CreateNetworkInterface
                      - ec2:DeleteNetworkInterface
                      - ec2:DescribeInstances
                      - ec2:AttachNetworkInterface
                    Resource: '*'
    
    Outputs:
      # ServerlessRestApi is an implicit API created out of Events key under Serverless::Function
      # Find out more about other implicit resources you can reference within SAM
      # https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/docs/internals/generated_resources.rst#api
      HelloWorldApi:
        Description: "API Gateway endpoint URL for Prod stage for functions"
        Value: !Sub "https://${ServerlessRestApi}.execute-api.${AWS::Region}.amazonaws.com/Prod/"
```

**template_user.yaml**

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Description: >
  aws-restapi

  Sample SAM Template for aws-restapi

    Globals:
      Function:
        Timeout: 5
        VpcConfig:
            SecurityGroupIds:
              - sg-041f2****cd921e8e
            SubnetIds:
              - subnet-03***b2d
              - subnet-c4d***cb
              - subnet-af5***8
              - subnet-74***f28
              - subnet-d139***c
              - subnet-e9***bd7
      
    
    Resources:
      GetUserRoleByIDFunction:
        Type: AWS::Serverless::Function # More info about Function Resource: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#awsserverlessfunction
        Properties:
          CodeUri: aws-restapi/
          Handler: source/user-role/userrole-getbyid.getUserRoleByID
          Runtime: nodejs14.x
          Events: 
            GetUserRoleByIDAPIEvent:
              Type: Api # More info about API Event Source: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#api
              Properties:
                Path: /userrole/getbyid
                Method: get
    
      GetUserRoleByUserFunction:
        Type: AWS::Serverless::Function # More info about Function Resource: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#awsserverlessfunction
        Properties:
          CodeUri: aws-restapi/
          Handler: source/user-role/userrole-getbyuser.getUserRoleByUser
          Runtime: nodejs14.x
          Events:
            GetUserRoleByUserAPIEvent:
              Type: Api # More info about API Event Source: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#api
              Properties:
                Path: /userrole/getbyuser
                Method: get
       # DependsOn: GetUserRoleByIDFunction
      GetUserRoleByRoleFunction:
        Type: AWS::Serverless::Function # More info about Function Resource: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#awsserverlessfunction
        Properties:
          CodeUri: aws-restapi/
          Handler: source/user-role/userrole-getbyrole.getAllUsersByRole
          Runtime: nodejs14.x
          Events:
            GetUserRoleByRoleAPIEvent:
              Type: Api # More info about API Event Source: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#api
              Properties:
                Path: /userrole/getbyrole
                Method: get
        #DependsOn: GetUserRoleByUserFunction
      SaveUserRoleFunction:
        Type: AWS::Serverless::Function # More info about Function Resource: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#awsserverlessfunction
        Properties:
          CodeUri: aws-restapi/
          Handler: source/user-role/userrole-save.saveUserRole
          Runtime: nodejs14.x
          Events:
            SaveUserRoleAPIEvent:
              Type: Api # More info about API Event Source: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#api
              Properties:
                Path: /userrole/save
                Method: post
       # DependsOn: GetUserRoleByRoleFunction
      UpdateUserRoleFunction:
        Type: AWS::Serverless::Function # More info about Function Resource: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#awsserverlessfunction
        Properties:
          CodeUri: aws-restapi/
          Handler: source/user-role/userrole-update.updateeUserRole
          Runtime: nodejs14.x
          Events:
            UpdateUserRoleAPIEvent:
              Type: Api # More info about API Event Source: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#api
              Properties:
                Path: /userrole/update
                Method: post
        #DependsOn: SaveUserRoleFunction
```

**template_two.yaml**

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Description: >
  aws-restapi

  Sample SAM Template for aws-restapi

Globals:
  Function:
    Timeout: 5
    VpcConfig:
        SecurityGroupIds:
          - sg-041f24xxxxd921e8e
        SubnetIds:
          - subnet-0381xxxd
          - subnet-c4dxxxcb
          - subnet-af5xxxc8
          - subnet-748xxx28
          - subnet-d139xxx9c
          - subnet-e9e8xxx7

Resources:
  GetAllPromotionsFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function # More info about Function Resource: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#awsserverlessfunction
    
    Properties:
      CodeUri: aws-restapi/
      Handler: source/promotions/promotions-getall.getAllPromotions
      Runtime: nodejs14.x
      Events:
        GetAllPromotionsAPIEvent:
          Type: Api # More info about API Event Source: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#api
          Properties:
            Path: /promotions/getall
            Method: get
  SavePromotionsFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function # More info about Function Resource: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#awsserverlessfunction
    
    Properties:
      CodeUri: aws-restapi/
      Handler: source/promotions/promotions-save.savePromotions
      Runtime: nodejs14.x
      Events:
        SavePromotionsAPIEvent:
          Type: Api # More info about API Event Source: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#api
          Properties:
            Path: /promotions/save
            Method: post
  UpdatePromotionsFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function # More info about Function Resource: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#awsserverlessfunction
    
    Properties:
      CodeUri: aws-restapi/
      Handler: source/promotions/promotions-update.updatePromotions
      Runtime: nodejs14.x
      Events:
        UpdatePromotionsAPIEvent:
          Type: Api # More info about API Event Source: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#api
          Properties:
            Path: /promotions/update
            Method: post


  GetAllStaticInfoFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function # More info about Function Resource: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#awsserverlessfunction
    
    Properties:
      CodeUri: aws-restapi/
      Handler: source/static-info/staticinfo-getall.getAllStaticInfo
      Runtime: nodejs14.x
      Events:
        GetAllStaticInfoAPIEvent:
          Type: Api # More info about API Event Source: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#api
          Properties:
            Path: /staticinfo/getall
            Method: get
  SaveStaticInfoFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function # More info about Function Resource: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#awsserverlessfunction
    
    Properties:
      CodeUri: aws-restapi/
      Handler: source/static-info/staticinfo-save.saveStaticInfo
      Runtime: nodejs14.x
      Events:
        SaveStaticInfoAPIEvent:
          Type: Api # More info about API Event Source: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#api
          Properties:
            Path: /staticinfo/save
            Method: post
  UpdateStaticInfoFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function # More info about Function Resource: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#awsserverlessfunction
    
    Properties:
      CodeUri: aws-restapi/
      Handler: source/static-info/staticinfo-update.updateStaticInfo
      Runtime: nodejs14.x
      Events:
        UpdateStaticInfoAPIEvent:
          Type: Api # More info about API Event Source: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#api
          Properties:
            Path: /staticinfo/update
            Method: post
```

This worked, but I noticed that API Gateway assigned different URLs for each stack I create. In this example I have two stacks and API Gateway did create 2 URLs.

1. `template.yaml` URL - https://ez5khz***.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/Prod/
2. `template_user.yaml` URL - https://7imy9b6***.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/Prod/
   . `template_two.yaml` URL - https://8awey9b6***.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/Prod/

I want the URL that was made with `template.yaml` to be applied to all lambda functions, regardless of which nested stack it is in. I also have a plan to later assign a domain into this.

How I can get this to work under a one URL?

**---------------UPDATE-------------------**

Following the advices provided by LRutten, i updated my code as below.

**template.yaml**

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Description: >
  aws-restapi

  Sample SAM Template for aws-restapi
  
# More info about Globals: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/docs/globals.rst
Globals:
  Function:
    Timeout: 5
    VpcConfig:
        SecurityGroupIds:
          - sg-041f2xxxd921e8e
        SubnetIds:
          - subnet-03xxxb2d
          - subnet-c4dxxxcb

Resources:
  ApiGatewayApi:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Api
    Properties:
      StageName: prod

  GetAllAccountingTypesFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function # More info about Function Resource: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#awsserverlessfunction
    Properties:
      CodeUri: aws-restapi/
      Handler: source/accounting-types/accountingtypes-getall.getallaccountingtypes
      Runtime: nodejs14.x
      Events:
        GetAllAccountingTypesAPIEvent:
          Type: Api # More info about API Event Source: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#api
          Properties:
            Path: /accountingtypes/getall
            Method: get
            RestApiId:
              Ref: ApiGatewayApi
  GetAccountingTypeByIDFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function # More info about Function Resource: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#awsserverlessfunction
    Properties:
      CodeUri: aws-restapi/
      Handler: source/accounting-types/accountingtypes-byid.getbyid
      Runtime: nodejs14.x
      Events:
        GetAllAccountingTypesAPIEvent:
          Type: Api # More info about API Event Source: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#api
          Properties:
            Path: /accountingtypes/getbyid
            Method: get
            RestApiId:
              Ref: ApiGatewayApi
  
  NestedStackTwo:
    Type: AWS::CloudFormation::Stack
    Properties:
      TemplateURL: nestedstack.yaml

  LambdaRole:
    Type: 'AWS::IAM::Role'
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: "2012-10-17"
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service:
                - lambda.amazonaws.com
            Action:
              - 'sts:AssumeRole'
      Path: /
      ManagedPolicyArns:
        - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole
      Policies:
        - PolicyName: root
          PolicyDocument:
            Version: "2012-10-17"
            Statement:
              - Effect: Allow
                Action:
                  - ec2:DescribeNetworkInterfaces
                  - ec2:CreateNetworkInterface
                  - ec2:DeleteNetworkInterface
                  - ec2:DescribeInstances
                  - ec2:AttachNetworkInterface
                Resource: '*'

Outputs:
  HelloWorldApi:
    Description: "API Gateway endpoint URL for Prod stage for functions"
    Value: !Sub "https://${ServerlessRestApi}.execute-api.${AWS::Region}.amazonaws.com/Prod/"
```

**netedstack.yaml**

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Description: >
  aws-restapi

  Sample SAM Template for aws-restapi

Globals:
  Function:
    Timeout: 5
    VpcConfig:
        SecurityGroupIds:
          - sg-041f2459dcd921e8e
        SubnetIds:
          - subnet-03xxxx2d
          - subnet-c4dxxxxcb

Parameters:
   ApiId: ApiGatewayApi

Resources:
  GetAllPromotionsFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function # More info about Function Resource: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#awsserverlessfunction
    Properties:
      CodeUri: aws-restapi/
      Handler: source/promotions/promotions-getall.getAllPromotions
      Runtime: nodejs14.x
      Events:
        GetAllPromotionsAPIEvent:
          Type: Api # More info about API Event Source: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#api
          Properties:
            Path: /promotions/getall
            Method: get
            RestApiId:
              Ref: !Ref ApiId
  SavePromotionsFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function # More info about Function Resource: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#awsserverlessfunction
    Properties:
      CodeUri: aws-restapi/
      Handler: source/promotions/promotions-save.savePromotions
      Runtime: nodejs14.x
      Events:
        SavePromotionsAPIEvent:
          Type: Api # More info about API Event Source: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#api
          Properties:
            Path: /promotions/save
            Method: post
            RestApiId:
              Ref: !Ref ApiId
  UpdatePromotionsFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function # More info about Function Resource: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#awsserverlessfunction
    Properties:
      CodeUri: aws-restapi/
      Handler: source/promotions/promotions-update.updatePromotions
      Runtime: nodejs14.x
      Events:
        UpdatePromotionsAPIEvent:
          Type: Api # More info about API Event Source: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#api
          Properties:
            Path: /promotions/update
            Method: post
            RestApiId:
              Ref: !Ref ApiId


  GetAllStaticInfoFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function # More info about Function Resource: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#awsserverlessfunction
    Properties:
      CodeUri: aws-restapi/
      Handler: source/static-info/staticinfo-getall.getAllStaticInfo
      Runtime: nodejs14.x
      Events:
        GetAllStaticInfoAPIEvent:
          Type: Api # More info about API Event Source: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#api
          Properties:
            Path: /staticinfo/getall
            Method: get
            RestApiId:
              Ref: !Ref ApiId
  SaveStaticInfoFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function # More info about Function Resource: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#awsserverlessfunction
    Properties:
      CodeUri: aws-restapi/
      Handler: source/static-info/staticinfo-save.saveStaticInfo
      Runtime: nodejs14.x
      Events:
        SaveStaticInfoAPIEvent:
          Type: Api # More info about API Event Source: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#api
          Properties:
            Path: /staticinfo/save
            Method: post
            RestApiId:
              Ref: !Ref ApiId
  UpdateStaticInfoFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function # More info about Function Resource: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#awsserverlessfunction
    Properties:
      CodeUri: aws-restapi/
      Handler: source/static-info/staticinfo-update.updateStaticInfo
      Runtime: nodejs14.x
      Events:
        UpdateStaticInfoAPIEvent:
          Type: Api # More info about API Event Source: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#api
          Properties:
            Path: /staticinfo/update
            Method: post
            RestApiId:
              Ref: !Ref ApiId
```

However, I can't build this project with `sam build`. I get the following error.

```
InvalidSamDocumentException(
samcli.commands.validate.lib.exceptions.InvalidSamDocumentException: [InvalidResourceException('GetAllPromotionsFunction', 'Event with id [GetAllPromotionsAPIEvent] is invalid. Api Event must reference an Api in the same template.')
```

Above error is generated for all the functions in the nested stack. How can I fix this?

Comment: You have only one `NestedStack`, so I'm not sure what is the issue? Why would you get two APIs from it?

Comment: @Marcin: Hi Marcin, I am not sure what you meant . I do have many stacks in the real case, here added just two. The API Gateway URL my nested stack get is different from the one my Root stack gets. That is the problem here.

Comment: Its different because you are create new API. If you want to use the API from the root stack, why not pass its reference to the nested stack as an input parameter to it?

Comment: @Marcin: To make sure there are no confusions, I added another nested stack

Comment: @Marcin: I do not have a deep knowledge on this Marcin. I am learning on the go. Do you mind showing me how to do it taking my code as an example? I will greatly appreciate that effort.

Comment: @Marcin: Hello?

Comment: @Marcin: Hi Marcin, I tried what you suggested. Now it is giving me the error `Api Event must reference an Api in the same template.`. A new question is here, please help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68979324/aws-cloudformation-how-to-fix-api-event-must-reference-an-api-in-the-same-temp/68979395?noredirect=1#comment121909743_68979395

Answer (score 1):

I think Marcin is right in the sense that in your top-level stack you can define your own `AWS::Serverless::Api` resource. Its a bit more effort than letting SAM do everything for you but it gives you the flexibility you want.

You can pass on the Api ID to other nested stacks using a simple !Ref.

For this to work, in the nested stack you need an `ApiId` parameter, which you then use in all of your defined lambdas:

```
Parameters:
   ApiId: ....

.....
Resources:
.....
      Events:
        UpdatePromotionsAPIEvent:
          Type: Api # More info about API Event Source: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#api
          Properties:
            Path: /promotions/update
            Method: post
            RestApiId: !Ref ApiId
```

I haven't tried this myself, but I think it should work?

Comment: Hello. This is which `yaml` file you want make me do to edits? Also API Id, what should I put there?

Comment: In the *nested* stack, you have to add a parameter, and the line `RestApiId: !Ref ApiId` to each lambda. In the top level stack, you define the `AWS::Serverless::Api` resource. Docs are quite extensive: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-resource-api.html.

Comment: Thank you. I tried your advice. It is now giving me `Api Event must reference an Api in the same template.` error. I updated my question, please check,

Comment: This is not possible as `RestApiId` cannot reference an AWS::Serverless::Api resource defined in another template. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-property-function-api.html