# AWS Cloudformation: How to fix "Api Event must reference an Api in the same template" error?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, aws-api-gateway, aws-sam

I am trying to split my stack into nested stack because i hit the AWS Max stack resource limit. I am building a REST API. I want to use a one API Gateway for all the stacks.  Below is my code.

**template.yaml**

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Description: >
  aws-restapi

  Sample SAM Template for aws-restapi
  
# More info about Globals: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/docs/globals.rst
Globals:
  Function:
    Timeout: 5
    VpcConfig:
        SecurityGroupIds:
          - sg-041f2xxxd921e8e
        SubnetIds:
          - subnet-03xxxb2d
          - subnet-c4dxxxcb

Resources:
  ApiGatewayApi:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Api
    Properties:
      StageName: prod

  GetAllAccountingTypesFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function # More info about Function Resource: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#awsserverlessfunction
    Properties:
      CodeUri: aws-restapi/
      Handler: source/accounting-types/accountingtypes-getall.getallaccountingtypes
      Runtime: nodejs14.x
      Events:
        GetAllAccountingTypesAPIEvent:
          Type: Api # More info about API Event Source: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#api
          Properties:
            Path: /accountingtypes/getall
            Method: get
            RestApiId:
              Ref: ApiGatewayApi
  GetAccountingTypeByIDFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function # More info about Function Resource: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#awsserverlessfunction
    Properties:
      CodeUri: aws-restapi/
      Handler: source/accounting-types/accountingtypes-byid.getbyid
      Runtime: nodejs14.x
      Events:
        GetAllAccountingTypesAPIEvent:
          Type: Api # More info about API Event Source: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#api
          Properties:
            Path: /accountingtypes/getbyid
            Method: get
            RestApiId:
              Ref: ApiGatewayApi
  
  NestedStackTwo:
    Type: AWS::CloudFormation::Stack
    Properties:
      TemplateURL: nestedstack.yaml

  LambdaRole:
    Type: 'AWS::IAM::Role'
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: "2012-10-17"
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service:
                - lambda.amazonaws.com
            Action:
              - 'sts:AssumeRole'
      Path: /
      ManagedPolicyArns:
        - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole
      Policies:
        - PolicyName: root
          PolicyDocument:
            Version: "2012-10-17"
            Statement:
              - Effect: Allow
                Action:
                  - ec2:DescribeNetworkInterfaces
                  - ec2:CreateNetworkInterface
                  - ec2:DeleteNetworkInterface
                  - ec2:DescribeInstances
                  - ec2:AttachNetworkInterface
                Resource: '*'

Outputs:
  HelloWorldApi:
    Description: "API Gateway endpoint URL for Prod stage for functions"
    Value: !Sub "https://${ServerlessRestApi}.execute-api.${AWS::Region}.amazonaws.com/Prod/"
```

**nestedstack.yaml**

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Description: >
  aws-restapi

  Sample SAM Template for aws-restapi

Globals:
  Function:
    Timeout: 5
    VpcConfig:
        SecurityGroupIds:
          - sg-041f2459dcd921e8e
        SubnetIds:
          - subnet-03xxxx2d
          - subnet-c4dxxxxcb

Parameters:
   ApiId: ApiGatewayApi

Resources:
  GetAllPromotionsFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function # More info about Function Resource: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#awsserverlessfunction
    Properties:
      CodeUri: aws-restapi/
      Handler: source/promotions/promotions-getall.getAllPromotions
      Runtime: nodejs14.x
      Events:
        GetAllPromotionsAPIEvent:
          Type: Api # More info about API Event Source: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#api
          Properties:
            Path: /promotions/getall
            Method: get
            RestApiId:
              Ref: !Ref ApiId
  SavePromotionsFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function # More info about Function Resource: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#awsserverlessfunction
    Properties:
      CodeUri: aws-restapi/
      Handler: source/promotions/promotions-save.savePromotions
      Runtime: nodejs14.x
      Events:
        SavePromotionsAPIEvent:
          Type: Api # More info about API Event Source: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#api
          Properties:
            Path: /promotions/save
            Method: post
            RestApiId:
              Ref: !Ref ApiId
  UpdatePromotionsFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function # More info about Function Resource: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#awsserverlessfunction
    Properties:
      CodeUri: aws-restapi/
      Handler: source/promotions/promotions-update.updatePromotions
      Runtime: nodejs14.x
      Events:
        UpdatePromotionsAPIEvent:
          Type: Api # More info about API Event Source: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#api
          Properties:
            Path: /promotions/update
            Method: post
            RestApiId:
              Ref: !Ref ApiId


  GetAllStaticInfoFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function # More info about Function Resource: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#awsserverlessfunction
    Properties:
      CodeUri: aws-restapi/
      Handler: source/static-info/staticinfo-getall.getAllStaticInfo
      Runtime: nodejs14.x
      Events:
        GetAllStaticInfoAPIEvent:
          Type: Api # More info about API Event Source: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#api
          Properties:
            Path: /staticinfo/getall
            Method: get
            RestApiId:
              Ref: !Ref ApiId
  SaveStaticInfoFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function # More info about Function Resource: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#awsserverlessfunction
    Properties:
      CodeUri: aws-restapi/
      Handler: source/static-info/staticinfo-save.saveStaticInfo
      Runtime: nodejs14.x
      Events:
        SaveStaticInfoAPIEvent:
          Type: Api # More info about API Event Source: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#api
          Properties:
            Path: /staticinfo/save
            Method: post
            RestApiId:
              Ref: !Ref ApiId
  UpdateStaticInfoFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function # More info about Function Resource: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#awsserverlessfunction
    Properties:
      CodeUri: aws-restapi/
      Handler: source/static-info/staticinfo-update.updateStaticInfo
      Runtime: nodejs14.x
      Events:
        UpdateStaticInfoAPIEvent:
          Type: Api # More info about API Event Source: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#api
          Properties:
            Path: /staticinfo/update
            Method: post
            RestApiId:
              Ref: !Ref ApiId
```

However, I can't build this project with `sam build`. I get the following error.

```
InvalidSamDocumentException(
samcli.commands.validate.lib.exceptions.InvalidSamDocumentException: [InvalidResourceException('GetAllPromotionsFunction', 'Event with id [GetAllPromotionsAPIEvent] is invalid. Api Event must reference an Api in the same template.')
```

Above error is generated for all the functions in the nested stack. If you need the full stacktrace, it is below.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.29.0/libexec/lib/python3.8/site-packages/samcli/lib/samlib/wrapper.py", line 68, in run_plugins
    parser.parse(template_copy, all_plugins)  # parse() will run all configured plugins
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.29.0/libexec/lib/python3.8/site-packages/samcli/lib/samlib/wrapper.py", line 88, in parse
    sam_plugins.act(LifeCycleEvents.before_transform_template, sam_template)
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.29.0/libexec/lib/python3.8/site-packages/samtranslator/plugins/__init__.py", line 136, in act
    raise ex
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.29.0/libexec/lib/python3.8/site-packages/samtranslator/plugins/__init__.py", line 133, in act
    getattr(plugin, method_name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.29.0/libexec/lib/python3.8/site-packages/samtranslator/plugins/api/implicit_api_plugin.py", line 100, in on_before_transform_template
    raise InvalidDocumentException(errors)
samtranslator.model.exceptions.InvalidDocumentException: [InvalidResourceException('GetAllPromotionsFunction', 'Event with id [GetAllPromotionsAPIEvent] is invalid. Api Event must reference an Api in the same template.'), InvalidResourceException('SavePromotionsFunction', 'Event with id [SavePromotionsAPIEvent] is invalid. Api Event must reference an Api in the same template.'), InvalidResourceException('UpdatePromotionsFunction', 'Event with id [UpdatePromotionsAPIEvent] is invalid. Api Event must reference an Api in the same template.'), InvalidResourceException('GetAllStaticInfoFunction', 'Event with id [GetAllStaticInfoAPIEvent] is invalid. Api Event must reference an Api in the same template.'), InvalidResourceException('SaveStaticInfoFunction', 'Event with id [SaveStaticInfoAPIEvent] is invalid. Api Event must reference an Api in the same template.'), InvalidResourceException('UpdateStaticInfoFunction', 'Event with id [UpdateStaticInfoAPIEvent] is invalid. Api Event must reference an Api in the same template.')]

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/homebrew/bin/sam", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(cli())
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.29.0/libexec/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 829, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.29.0/libexec/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 782, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.29.0/libexec/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1259, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.29.0/libexec/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1066, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.29.0/libexec/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 610, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.29.0/libexec/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/decorators.py", line 73, in new_func
    return ctx.invoke(f, obj, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.29.0/libexec/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 610, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.29.0/libexec/lib/python3.8/site-packages/samcli/lib/telemetry/metric.py", line 153, in wrapped
    raise exception  # pylint: disable=raising-bad-type
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.29.0/libexec/lib/python3.8/site-packages/samcli/lib/telemetry/metric.py", line 122, in wrapped
    return_value = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.29.0/libexec/lib/python3.8/site-packages/samcli/lib/utils/version_checker.py", line 42, in wrapped
    actual_result = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.29.0/libexec/lib/python3.8/site-packages/samcli/cli/main.py", line 90, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.29.0/libexec/lib/python3.8/site-packages/samcli/commands/build/command.py", line 210, in cli
    do_cli(
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.29.0/libexec/lib/python3.8/site-packages/samcli/commands/build/command.py", line 279, in do_cli
    with BuildContext(
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.29.0/libexec/lib/python3.8/site-packages/samcli/commands/build/build_context.py", line 84, in __enter__
    self._stacks, remote_stack_full_paths = SamLocalStackProvider.get_stacks(
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.29.0/libexec/lib/python3.8/site-packages/samcli/lib/providers/sam_stack_provider.py", line 242, in get_stacks
    stacks_in_child, remote_stack_full_paths_in_child = SamLocalStackProvider.get_stacks(
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.29.0/libexec/lib/python3.8/site-packages/samcli/lib/providers/sam_stack_provider.py", line 236, in get_stacks
    current = SamLocalStackProvider(
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.29.0/libexec/lib/python3.8/site-packages/samcli/lib/providers/sam_stack_provider.py", line 51, in __init__
    self._template_dict = self.get_template(
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.29.0/libexec/lib/python3.8/site-packages/samcli/lib/providers/sam_base_provider.py", line 189, in get_template
    template_dict = SamTranslatorWrapper(template_dict, parameter_values=parameters_values).run_plugins()
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.29.0/libexec/lib/python3.8/site-packages/samcli/lib/samlib/wrapper.py", line 70, in run_plugins
    raise InvalidSamDocumentException(
samcli.commands.validate.lib.exceptions.InvalidSamDocumentException: [InvalidResourceException('GetAllPromotionsFunction', 'Event with id [GetAllPromotionsAPIEvent] is invalid. Api Event must reference an Api in the same template.'), InvalidResourceException('SavePromotionsFunction', 'Event with id [SavePromotionsAPIEvent] is invalid. Api Event must reference an Api in the same template.'), InvalidResourceException('UpdatePromotionsFunction', 'Event with id [UpdatePromotionsAPIEvent] is invalid. Api Event must reference an Api in the same template.'), InvalidResourceException('GetAllStaticInfoFunction', 'Event with id [GetAllStaticInfoAPIEvent] is invalid. Api Event must reference an Api in the same template.'), InvalidResourceException('SaveStaticInfoFunction', 'Event with id [SaveStaticInfoAPIEvent] is invalid. Api Event must reference an Api in the same template.'), InvalidResourceException('UpdateStaticInfoFunction', 'Event with id [UpdateStaticInfoAPIEvent] is invalid. Api Event must reference an Api in the same template.')] ('GetAllPromotionsFunction', 'Event with id [GetAllPromotionsAPIEvent] is invalid. Api Event must reference an Api in the same template.') ('GetAllStaticInfoFunction', 'Event with id [GetAllStaticInfoAPIEvent] is invalid. Api Event must reference an Api in the same template.') ('SavePromotionsFunction', 'Event with id [SavePromotionsAPIEvent] is invalid. Api Event must reference an Api in the same template.') ('SaveStaticInfoFunction', 'Event with id [SaveStaticInfoAPIEvent] is invalid. Api Event must reference an Api in the same template.') ('UpdatePromotionsFunction', 'Event with id [UpdatePromotionsAPIEvent] is invalid. Api Event must reference an Api in the same template.') ('UpdateStaticInfoFunction', 'Event with id [UpdateStaticInfoAPIEvent] is invalid. Api Event must reference an Api in the same template.')
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look into the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-property-function-api.html#sam-property-function-api-properties) for the API Event for the serverless function, they write:

> RestApiId Identifier of a RestApi resource, which must contain an
> operation with the given path and method. Typically, this is set to
> reference an AWS::Serverless::Api resource defined in this template.
>
> If you don't define this property, AWS SAM creates a default
> AWS::Serverless::Api resource using a generated OpenApi document. That
> resource contains a union of all paths and methods defined by Api
> events in the same template that do not specify a RestApiId.
>
> **This cannot reference an AWS::Serverless::Api resource defined in**
> **another template.**

**template.yaml:**

```
NestedStackTwo:
    Type: AWS::CloudFormation::Stack
    Properties:
      TemplateURL: nestedstack.yaml
      Parameters:
        ApiId: !Ref ApiGatewayApi
```

**nestedstack.yaml:**

```
Parameters:
   ApiId:
     Type: string
```

Comment: So basically speaking, I cant use it in multiple templates? Then how am I supposed to use the same API Gateway for my functions in multiple nested stacks?

Comment: I just visited the link you provided. Cannot find the statement you are referencing.

Comment: Under 'RestApiId'. You can not use it currently, but in this thread there are some ongoing discussions for workarounds: https://github.com/aws/serverless-application-model/issues/349

Comment: okay, we have a problem there then. In this kind of a scenario, what is the best approach to make?

Comment: Is it impossible for you to use two API Gateways? Because this would be currently the way to go

Comment: I can. But in case of an app, it will point to one gateway. For an example, no app will load data from `https://link1.com/something` for the first 50 methods and use  `https://link2.com/something` for the next 50 and so on right? At least can we assign a domain to this and use the same domain name across the API Gateways?

Comment: Same Domain name should possible as far as I know.

Comment: Same domain name across multiple stacks?

Comment: Yes, that should be possible.

Comment: No problem, if this helped you, an upvote / accept would be appreciated

Comment: I guess we have a problem in the domain name too.... - https://youtu.be/Ro0rgeLDkO4?t=108

Comment: Anyway, Robert, can you do me a favour? Do you mind checking my code and letting me know whether the way I referenced is correct? I have a doubt there.

Comment: Which reference exactly?

Comment: The way I created `AWS::Serverless::Api` resource in the root stack and the way i accessed it it in my nested stack

Comment: Thank you Robert. Anyway, I give up finding a solution for this. I found the official github thread on this, this is an issue from 2018 and AWS team is just asking user opinions without a solutions, that's it.

Comment: I actually linked that thread in the comments.

Comment: No, it was another thread with a 2021 update. I will find and post. Anyway, now my app has to access multiple API gateway end points isnt it.... I will try to map them all into a custom domain and see. Anyway, when adding the authentication and authorization to the api gateway, this means I have to add them gateway by gateway? In that case, does that mean before accessing each gateway my app has to sign in ??

Comment: Robert, do you think you can help me here? - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69009267/unable-to-configure-firebase-authorization-to-aws-api-gateway