# Unable to configure Firebase authorization to AWS API Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, firebase, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, aws-sam

I am developing a REST API with `AWS Lambda` and `API Gateway`. I am trying to configure Firebase authorization to this. FYI, I have not touched the AWS Web Console, just trying to do everything with the `aws-sam`.

Below is my code. I have not changed anything below, code is pasted as it is.

**template.yaml**

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Description: >
  aws-restapi

  Sample SAM Template for aws-restapi
  
# More info about Globals: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/docs/globals.rst
Globals:
  Function:
    Timeout: 5
    VpcConfig:
        SecurityGroupIds:
          - sg-041f2459dcd921e8e
        SubnetIds:
          - subnet-038025dd
          - subnet-c44254cb

Parameters:
  FirebaseProjectId: 
    Type: String

Resources:

  AuthGatewayHttpApi:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::HttpApi
    Properties:
      Auth:
        Authorizers:
          FirebaseAuthorizer:
            IdentitySource: $request.header.Authorization
            JwtConfiguration:
              audience:
                - !Ref aws-7e5db
              issuer: !Sub https://securetoken.google.com/${aws-7e5db}
        DefaultAuthorizer: FirebaseAuthorizer
      StageName: "Prod"
  
  AuthFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      CodeUri: aws-restapi/
      Handler: source/testfile.lambdaHandler
      Runtime: nodejs14.x
      Events:
        Gateway:
          Type: HttpApi
          Properties:
            ApiId: !Ref AuthGatewayHttpApi
            Path: /hello
            Method: GET
```

**testfile.js**

```
exports.lambdaHandler = async (event) => {
    try {
      // If an authenticated request is made to JWT
      // Which we expect is what will happen
      // So we simply return the claims
      const jwt = event.requestContext.authorizer.jwt.claims;
  
      // Let us get the email from the claims
      // Note the email will not be available if Sign in via phone
      const email = jwt.claims.email;
  
      return {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: JSON.stringify({ jwt: jwt, email: email }),
      };
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
      return {
        statusCode: 400,
        body: JSON.stringify({ error: "Please check logs" }),
      };
    }
  };
```

This builds, but cannot deploy. It simply throws the following error.

```
Error: Failed to create changeset for the stack: aws-restapi, An error occurred (ValidationError) when calling the CreateChangeSet operation: Parameters: [FirebaseProjectId] must have values
```

What is wrong here? Plus, my firebase auth configuration is correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue for this. I had to pass the parameter. Passing a parameter should be done when you are deploying. Do the following.

```
sam deploy --guided
```

Then follow the process, it will ask you for the parameter value. You have to do this whether you have done a deployment before or not.

Then, my code was wrong too. This is how it should be.

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Description: >
  aws-restapi

  Sample SAM Template for aws-restapi
  
# More info about Globals: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/docs/globals.rst
Globals:
  Function:
    Timeout: 5
    VpcConfig:
        SecurityGroupIds:
          - sg-041f2459dcd921e8e
        SubnetIds:
          - subnet-0381asa2d
          - subnet-c4dasascb


Parameters:
  FirebaseProjectId:
    Type: String

Resources:
  AuthGatewayHttpApi:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::HttpApi
    Properties:
      Auth:
        Authorizers:
          FirebaseAuthorizer:
            IdentitySource: $request.header.Authorization
            JwtConfiguration:
              audience:
                - !Ref FirebaseProjectId
              issuer: !Sub https://securetoken.google.com/${FirebaseProjectId}
        DefaultAuthorizer: FirebaseAuthorizer
  
  AuthFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      CodeUri: peresia-restapi/
      Handler: source/testfile.lambdaHandler
      Runtime: nodejs14.x
      Events:
        Gateway:
          Type: HttpApi
          Properties:
            ApiId: !Ref AuthGatewayHttpApi
            Path: /hello
            Method: get
```

Answer (score 1):

You are defining a parameter but not assigning a value to it.

```
Parameters:
  FirebaseProjectId: 
    Type: String
```

Either you delete it, or assign a value

Comment: I tried removing it. Then it gave me the error `Error: Failed to create changeset for the stack: aws-restapi, ex: Waiter ChangeSetCreateComplete failed: Waiter encountered a terminal failure state: For expression "Status" we matched expected path: "FAILED" Status: FAILED. Reason: Template error: variable names in Fn::Sub syntax must contain only alphanumeric characters, underscores, periods, and colons`

Comment: I really dont know how to assign a parameter into the parameter anyway

Comment: This is a different error though. Now the problem is the ${aws-7e5db}. You can not use hyphens in variables.

Comment: I found how to enter the parameter.

Comment: Robert, can you offer some help here? - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69049471/aws-why-i-am-unable-to-assign-a-custom-domain-to-the-nested-stack

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid this issue also by supplying a default value:

```
Parameters:
  FirebaseProjectId: 
    Type: String
    Default: "1111-2222-3333-44444"
```

Comment: Can you also help me here? - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69043426/how-to-configure-a-custom-domain-for-aws-api-gateway-using-aws-sam