# How to configure a custom domain for HttpApi using AWS SAM?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, aws-cli, amazon-route53, aws-sam

I am developing an API using AWS Lambda, AWS API Gateway and aws-sam. I have implemented firebase authentication. I also use nested stacks.

I am trying to use a custom domain for my API endpoints, so I can call like `api.mydomain.com/products`, `api.mydomain.com/sales` and so on. I have the domain ready, and a certificate from the AWS Certificate Manager. I even managed to deploy my `aws-sam` application without the domain configurations and then assign the custom domain and domain mappings manually via the `AWS API Gateway` web console.

But I need to do that part in the `aws-sam` itself. Below is what I tried.

**Root Stack**

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Description: >
  aws-restapi

  Sample SAM Template for aws-restapi
  
# More info about Globals: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/docs/globals.rst
Globals:
  Function:
    Timeout: 5
    VpcConfig:
        SecurityGroupIds:
          - sg-041f215425921e8e
        SubnetIds:
          - subnet-0251b2d


Parameters:
  FirebaseProjectId:
    Type: String
  
  DomainName:
    Type: String
    Default: api.example.com

Resources:
  AuthGatewayHttpApi:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::HttpApi
    Properties:
      Auth:
        Authorizers:
          FirebaseAuthorizer:
            IdentitySource: $request.header.Authorization
            JwtConfiguration:
              audience:
                - !Ref FirebaseProjectId
              issuer: !Sub https://securetoken.google.com/${FirebaseProjectId}
        DefaultAuthorizer: FirebaseAuthorizer

  AppDomainName:
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::DomainName
    Properties:
      CertificateArn: arn:aws:acm:us-east-1:xxxxxxx43:certificate/1axxxf-3234-xxx2f-a61c-924eeexxxx9
      DomainName: !Ref DomainName

  APIBasePathMapping:
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::BasePathMapping
    Properties:
      BasePath: "api"
      DomainName: !Ref AppDomainName
      Stage: "default"
      RestApiId: !Ref AuthGatewayHttpApi
  
  AuthFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      CodeUri: aws-restapi/
      Handler: source/testfile.lambdaHandler
      Runtime: nodejs14.x
      Events:
        Gateway:
          Type: HttpApi
          Properties:
            ApiId: !Ref AuthGatewayHttpApi
            Path: /hello
            Method: get

  GetAllAccountingTypesFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function # More info about Function Resource: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#awsserverlessfunction
    Properties:
      CodeUri: aws-restapi/
      Handler: source/accounting-types/accountingtypes-getall.getallaccountingtypes
      Runtime: nodejs14.x
      Events:
        GetAllAccountingTypesAPIEvent:
          Type: HttpApi # More info about API Event Source: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#api
          Properties:
            ApiId: !Ref AuthGatewayHttpApi
            Path: /accountingtypes/getall
            Method: get

  GetAccountingTypeByIDFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function # More info about Function Resource: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#awsserverlessfunction
    Properties:
      CodeUri: aws-restapi/
      Handler: source/accounting-types/accountingtypes-byid.getbyid
      Runtime: nodejs14.x
      Events:
        GetAllAccountingTypesAPIEvent:
          Type: HttpApi # More info about API Event Source: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#api
          Properties:
            Path: /accountingtypes/getbyid
            Method: get
```

**nested stack**

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Description: >
  aws-restapi

  Sample SAM Template for aws-restapi

Globals:
  Function:
    Timeout: 5
    VpcConfig:
        SecurityGroupIds:
          - sg-041f2459xxxx1e8e
        SubnetIds:
          - subnet-03xxxx2d

Parameters:
  FirebaseProjectId:
    Type: String

Resources:

  AuthGatewayHttpApi:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::HttpApi
    Properties:
      Auth:
        Authorizers:
          FirebaseAuthorizer:
            IdentitySource: $request.header.Authorization
            JwtConfiguration:
              audience:
                - !Ref FirebaseProjectId
              issuer: !Sub https://securetoken.google.com/${FirebaseProjectId}
        DefaultAuthorizer: FirebaseAuthorizer

  GetAllPromotionsFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function # More info about Function Resource: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#awsserverlessfunction
    Properties:
      CodeUri: aws-restapi/
      Handler: source/promotions/promotions-getall.getAllPromotions
      Runtime: nodejs14.x
      Events:
        GetAllPromotionsAPIEvent:
          Type: HttpApi # More info about API Event Source: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#api
          Properties:
            Path: /promotions/getall
            Method: get
            ApiId: !Ref AuthGatewayHttpApi
  SavePromotionsFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function # More info about Function Resource: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#awsserverlessfunction
    Properties:
      CodeUri: aws-restapi/
      Handler: source/promotions/promotions-save.savePromotions
      Runtime: nodejs14.x
      Events:
        SavePromotionsAPIEvent:
          Type: HttpApi # More info about API Event Source: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#api
          Properties:
            Path: /promotions/save
            Method: get
```

However I cant get this to work. i even tried applying this only for the root stack, then i ended up with the following error.

```
Mixing of REST APIs and HTTP APIs on the same domain name can only be accomplished through API Gateway's V2 DomainName interface. 
Currently, WebSocket APIs can only be attached to a domain name with other WebSocket APIs. 
This must also occur through API Gateway's V2 DomainName interface. 
(Service: AmazonApiGateway; Status Code: 400; Error Code: BadRequestException; Request ID: 2f44d53b-8175-47f5-8bc8-db5 19aa484e7; Proxy: null)
```

How can I successfully configure a custom domain to be used with the API Gateway?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the Domain property config,  here is an example:

```
AuthGatewayHttpApi:
  Type: AWS::Serverless::HttpApi
  Properties:
    Auth:
      Authorizers:
        FirebaseAuthorizer:
          IdentitySource: $request.header.Authorization
          JwtConfiguration:
            audience:
              - !Ref FirebaseProjectId
            issuer: !Sub https://securetoken.google.com/${FirebaseProjectId}
      DefaultAuthorizer: FirebaseAuthorizer
    Domain:
      DomainName: www.example.com
      CertificateArn: arn-example
      EndpointConfiguration: REGIONAL
      Route53:
        HostedZoneId: Z1PA6795UKMFR9
```

More info here : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-property-httpapi-httpapidomainconfiguration.html#sam-property-httpapi-httpapidomainconfiguration--examples

Comment: wow cool, what about the nested one please?

Comment: In the nested one, you know the API Gateway will automatically create a different end point for it. I need to add the custom domain there too, so I can call like `api.example.com/products`

Comment: I created a specific question for nested stacks as well, appreciate if you can take a look - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69049471/failed-to-create-api-gateway-domain-name-by-aws-sam

Comment: "what about the nested one please?" it would be the same changes to the `AWS::Serverless::HttpApi` resource definition

Comment: errrr... I didnt get you. I saw you have checked my other question as well, can you show me exactly what you meant? I am new to this, im sorry.