# AWS-SAM: How to re use a Route53 domain instead of re creating it?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-route53, aws-sam

I am developing an HTTP API. I need to use a custom domain with this. I already have the domain, and I generated the certificate from the `AWS Certificate manager` as well. My domain DNS is in `Amazon Route53`.

Now I am trying to attach this custom domain to my HTTP API. I also need to set the base path. I am using `AWS-SAM` template and below is what I tried.

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Description: >
  aws-restapi

  Sample SAM Template for aws-restapi
  
# More info about Globals: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/docs/globals.rst
Globals:
  Function:
    Timeout: 5
    VpcConfig:
        SecurityGroupIds:
          - sg-041f24sd125s51e8e
        SubnetIds:
          - subnet-05265b2d


Parameters:
  FirebaseProjectId:
    Type: String
  
  DomainName:
    Type: String
    Default: api.example.com

Resources:

  AuthGatewayHttpApi:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::HttpApi
    Properties:
      Domain:
        DomainName: !Ref DomainName
        CertificateArn: arn:aws:acm:us-east-1:xxxx:certificate/xxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxx
        Route53:
          HostedZoneId: Z096752626aDO8HB8C6
      Auth:
        Authorizers:
          FirebaseAuthorizer:
            IdentitySource: $request.header.Authorization
            JwtConfiguration:
              audience:
                - !Ref FirebaseProjectId
              issuer: !Sub https://securetoken.google.com/${FirebaseProjectId}
        DefaultAuthorizer: FirebaseAuthorizer
  
  AuthFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      CodeUri: aws-restapi/
      Handler: source/testfile.lambdaHandler
      Runtime: nodejs14.x
      Events:
        Gateway:
          Type: HttpApi
          Properties:
            ApiId: !Ref AuthGatewayHttpApi
            Path: /hello
            Method: get
```

This template builds fine but when deploying it throws the following error.

```
CREATE_FAILED                      AWS::Route53::RecordSetGroup       RecordSetGroupf015792d8d 

[Tried to create resource record set [name='api.example.com.',type='A'] but it already exists]
```

Well, the error says the truth, I have the domain already in place. I do not want to create the domain or a certificate again, I just want to use them here.

How can I get this done? also how can I set the `basePath` so i can access like `api.example.com/products` ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to configure a custom domain for AWS API Gateway using AWS SAM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69043426/how-to-configure-a-custom-domain-for-aws-api-gateway-using-aws-sam)

Comment: @petey: No I am sorry. It re creates, I dont need to re create. Atleast for the nested stacks I have, it should start referencing.

Answer (score 0):

You can't reuse this `DomainName` if it is pointing to a server or other AWS service like AWS Amplify. You can reuse this domain (or subdomain) only if it is already being used by API Gateway. So, if you can delete the DNS register, I recommend you to create it again with AWS SAM or create a different subdomain. If the subdomain is already being used by API Gateway, then you can create an `AWS::ApiGatewayV2::ApiMapping` resource.

### Creating the DNS Record with AWS SAM

In this case you can simply define the `BasePath` attribute of the Domain:

```
AuthGatewayHttpApi:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::HttpApi
    Properties:
      Domain:
        BasePath:
          - products
        DomainName: !Ref DomainName
        CertificateArn: arn:aws:acm:us-east-1:xxxx:certificate/xxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxx
        Route53:
          HostedZoneId: Z096752626aDO8HB8C6
      Auth:
        Authorizers:
          FirebaseAuthorizer:
            IdentitySource: $request.header.Authorization
            JwtConfiguration:
              audience:
                - !Ref FirebaseProjectId
              issuer: !Sub https://securetoken.google.com/${FirebaseProjectId}
        DefaultAuthorizer: FirebaseAuthorizer
```

### Creating an ApiMapping for an existing DomainName

In this case you won't define the `Domain` properties, it is only necessary to create the `AWS::ApiGatewayV2::ApiMapping` resource.

```
AuthGatewayHttpApi:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::HttpApi
    Properties:
      Auth:
        Authorizers:
          FirebaseAuthorizer:
            IdentitySource: $request.header.Authorization
            JwtConfiguration:
              audience:
                - !Ref FirebaseProjectId
              issuer: !Sub https://securetoken.google.com/${FirebaseProjectId}
        DefaultAuthorizer: FirebaseAuthorizer


AuthGatewayProductsMapping: # Creates the mapping for Reporting V1
    Type: AWS::ApiGatewayV2::ApiMapping
    Properties:
      ApiId: !Ref AuthGatewayHttpApi
      ApiMappingKey: products
      DomainName: !Ref DomainName
      Stage: Prod
```